# C# - Programatically click a ListView Column

Tags: c#, listview

Is there a way to programatically click on a ListView column just as if you would normally click on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, just figured it out using [this page](http://www.ureader.com/msg/144645329.aspx).

```
        ColumnClickEventArgs args = new ColumnClickEventArgs(0);
        listView1_ColumnClick(this, args);
```

Answer (score 4):

Can't you just raise the ColumnClick event and pass the column number in the ColumnClickEventArgs?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.columnclick.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.columnclickeventargs.aspx

Example... erm... not really, as I'm a good few hundred miles away from the nearest VS install and I'm not great at remembering syntax without it!

Sort of pseudocode attempt though...

```
//initialize your event arguments
    ColumnClickEventArgs eArgs = new ColumnClickEventArgs(columnindex);

//declare your method
private void myColumnClick(object o, ColumnClickEventArgs e)
{
//do your stuff
}

//call your method to do stuff
myColumnClick(ListView1, eArgs);
```

I mean, really all you're doing is actually passing the column number which was clicked along with the listview object through as if you were creating an event handler - you're just not actually creating an event handler, nor are you using the OnColumnClick event to fire it.

This might get shot down by someone, but AFAIK it should work...

Comment: Thank you, but I just figured it out using the page described in my answer below.  Pretty much the same thing though, so I'll give you and upvote.

Comment: Actually, I didn't. I went home and went to bed pretty much directly after posting my update. But thanks for the appreciation anyway. Not that I feel I need to, but I've upvoted it anyway. You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

The `ListView` control does absolutely nothing when you click on a column header; the only action taken would be performed in your own event handler anyway, so I would suggest simply calling your event handler (or factoring the common code out into a separate method, as would be best practice, and calling that whenever you want to simulate the clicking of a column header).